# How to add different static block to every category

Tags: magento

I want to add different static block to every category at some specific places on the page.
how would i do that.????

Reference http://www.partybounty.com
here the blocks in footer and banner are different for every category.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Layout Update XML (under custom design tab) on each category which can be controlled from the admin a bit like;

```
<reference name="content">
    <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="setPageTitleDisabled"><disabled>1</disabled></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="category.home.left">
        <action method="setElementTagName"><value>div</value></action>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>col-left sidebar col3</value></action>
        <block type="manufacturers/navigation_left" name="category.home.leftnav" template="manufacturers/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <remove name="category.description" />
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="category.home.right" after="category.home.left">
        <action method="setElementTagName"><value>div</value></action>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>category-home</value></action>
        <block type="core/template" name="category.home.description" template="catalog/category/description.phtml" />
    </block>
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.home.categories" template="catalog/navigation/categories.phtml" after="category.description">
        <action method="setIsMini"><value>1</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="homepage/homepagebanner" name="category.home.banner" after="category.home.categories">
        <action method="setIsCategory"><value>1</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="bestsellers/slider" name="category.home.bestsellers" after="category.home.banner" />
    <block type="bundlekits/slider" name="category.home.bundlekits" after="category.home.banner" />
    <block type="featuredproducts/listing" name="category.home.featured" after="category.home.bestsellers" />
</reference>
```

This gives you flexibility for different positioning and including different blocks on a per category basis, downside is it's a little time consuming to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

- Go to Admin Catalog - Manage categories
- choose your category
- go to Display Mode & choose either static block only or static block & products
- go to CMS block & choose the block you have created

See [How do I create and edit Static Blocks?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks)

If you want to add the static block to the header/footer you may have to 
add a field to your category see http://magecracker.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/how-to-add-custom-fieldattribute-in-magento-category/

then

```
<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
              ->createBlock('cms/block')
               ->setBlockId(Mage::registry('current_category')->getData('block id from custom field'))->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You call following in any category page. You can create different static blocks for each categories and call them depending on requirement or selecting from category edit page

```
<?php $app = Mage::app(); ?>
<?php echo $app->getLayout()
->createBlock('cms/block')
->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```